# How could Zurg know this about Buzz?

Tags: star-wars, toy-story-2

In *Toy Story 2*, in a dramatic scene, Zurg reveals that

> he is Buzz's father, in an obvious homage to the iconic *Empire Strikes Back* scene.

But how did Zurg know this? The only way he could have known that is if it was written on the box, which it obviously wasn't.

Comment: If you haven't seen Lightyear, then don't click this; https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a40414430/lightyear-angus-mcclane-zurg-twist-toy-story-2/

Comment: Buzz and Zurg are both aware of things they couldn't possibly know. For example, how do they both speak English?

Comment: @Valorum Hell, how do they both even speak? THEY'RE TOYS!

Comment: Maybe Zurg has seen the cartoon series *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command*. It exists in-universe and contains info about Zurg being Buzz' father (albeit jokingly).

Comment: Also Zurg could just be lying. Do we have any proof that he's actually Buzz's father?

Comment: no proof either that he isnt

Answer (score 7):

In Toy Story 1 Buzz seems to have knowledge beyond his simple character bio from the lines:

"Years of academy training wasted."

"Revenge is not an idea we promote on my planet."

Showing that he has some memories beyond just his current Space Ranger mission. It's possible Zurg also has knowledge of a more detailed backstory for himself beyond trying to take over the universe.